# how to call a methode from model in a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know how to call a method in model from controller but I am wondering how to call a method in controller from a model.

```
$this->load->model('dataOperateModel');
$this->dataOperateModel->saveData($formtype);
```

this loads a method in model. But I haven't seen anyone do the model to controller.
Is there any easy way to handle this.

Comment: If what you were writing had even vaguest resemblance of MVC-inspired design patterns, the structures from model layer would be completely unaware of presentation layer. What you are trying to do violates the core [idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of MVC-inspired patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not suppose to call a Controller actions from a Model. That defeats the point of data separation. I'd advise changing your question to be more specific to the problem that calling the action would solve.

To answer the question. Assuming the controller is called Posts.

```
//Import controller
App::import('Controller', 'Posts');
//Instantiation
$Posts = new PostsController;
//Load model, components...
$Posts->constructClasses();
//Call a method on the controller.
$Posts->index();
```

Comment: ok though above one is answere, you advice me to not do that. dont you?

Comment: @kiriappa Actually, the above code works for CakePHP and not Codeigniter. I would advise asking a more direct question that relates to what it is you are trying to do, rather then ask simply how to call actions on a controller. That would allow people to advise you on a solution that is follows the MVC design.

Answer (score 1):

Please chang this:

```
$this->load->model('dataOperateModel','dataOperate');
$this->dataOperate->saveData($formtype);
```